# How to add the integration of firebase option for windows application in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can not connect firebase to flutter, when I opened [![firebase_option.dart file] I found that windows are not connected, is there a way to connect it and if so, how to do it?

[image: firebase_option.dart file]

and bellow this code in there are implementations to all the applications that are returned except for windows and Linux.

Note: that I can run the application but when i try to log in to the home page i get an error, which is like the line bellow:
[![ Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showToast on channel PonnamKarthik/fluttertoast)]

Comment: The official Firebase SDKs for Flutter don't support Windows yet. Given that you tagged specifically with Firebase Authentication, have a look at these pure Dart packages that support that: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire_desktop and https://pub.dev/packages/firedart